# How can I find tweets that I've favorited that were written by a particular user?

Tags: twitter, tweet

I have favorited (stared) over 5,000 tweets. I'd like to be able to view only the tweets that I've favorited that were written by a particular user. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can you this API call to get your own (assuming you aren't behind a protected account):

`https://api.twitter.com/1/favorites.json?id=<yourTwitterName>&page=<pageNumber>`

Only 200 tweets appear at a time so you'll have to keep getting the pages updated.

You cannot separate the response into users that sent the tweets, but you could store the responses in a database or just copy paste them.

I was trying to find a service that could do this, but I couldn't find any. `Favstar.fm` came the closest, but it looks shady to me.

Comment: This version of Twitter API is currently deprecated.

Comment: the API doesn't work anymore